# Using a column from a dataframe in a new function, and then attaching the returned value from that function to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a data frame titled df with 6 columns.

```
['title' 'company' 'location' 'summary' 'days' 'Date']
```

I have a function called **Geocode(Location)** that takes a location as an input and returns a zipcode.

I need to figure out how to call the geocode(location) function on every location within the df dataframe and then insert the new zipcode output into the dateframe in a new column.
My desired output is a dataframe with **Title, Location, Date, DatePosted, Zipcode.**

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to get a new column based on `location`.

`df['zipcode'] = df['location'].transform(geocode)` assuming `geocode` is a function that operates on `location`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with `.apply()`:

```py
df.loc[:, 'ZipCode'] = df['Location'].apply(Geocode)
```